# Limit the amount of times font size can be increased and decreased

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, limit, font-size

In my ruby on rails application I am using the following javascript in the application.js to increase and decrease the text size:

```
function resizeText(multiplier) {
var elem = document.getElementById("sizeable");
var currentSize = elem.style.fontSize || 1;
elem.style.fontSize = ( parseFloat(currentSize) + (multiplier * 0.2)) + "em";
}
```

And this is called by these pieces of code in the view:

```
<img id="plustext" alt="INCREASE TEXT SIZE" src="images/makeTextBigger.jpg" onclick="resizeText(1)" /> | 
<img id="minustext" alt="DECREASE TEXT SIZE" src="images/makeTextSmaller.jpg" onclick="resizeText(-1)" />
```

The code then makes the text with the id sizeable bigger or smaller depending on what was clicked:

```
<tr id='sizeable'>
    <td><%= certificate.age_rating %></td>
    <td>
        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_certificate_path(certificate) %>
        <%= link_to 'Show', certificate_path(certificate) %>
        <%= link_to 'Destroy', certificate_path(certificate), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    </td>
</tr>
```

But what I want to do is restrict the amount of times the font size can be increased and decreased to 2 clicks.

I have tried this, and replaced my previous java script so my application.js now looks like this:

```
$(function(){
 $('#film_release_date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', 
    changeYear: true, maxDate: "5Y", minDate: "0D", changeMonth: true
  });
 });

var minSize = 1;
var maxSize = 5;

function resizeText(multiplier) {
    var elem = document.getElementById("sizeable");
    var newSize = parseFloat(elem.style.fontSize) + multiplier * 0.2;
    if (newSize < minSize) newSize = minSize;
    if (newSize > maxSize) newSize = maxSize;
    elem.style.fontSize = newSize + "em";
}
```

But this appears not to work.

How can I adapt my code to do this? I do not have much knowledge of java script.

Comment: Don't tag non-Java questions as Java.

Comment: Are you sure you want to restrict it to 2 clicks? I guess you want to restrict the max font size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adapting the answer provided by @Andrei Nikolaenko, adding this into my application.js worked:

```
var minSize = 1;
var maxSize = 1.5;

function resizeText(multiplier) {
  var elem = document.getElementById("sizeable");
  var currentSize = elem.style.fontSize || 1;
  var newSize = parseFloat(currentSize) + multiplier * 0.2;
  if (newSize < minSize) newSize = minSize;
  if (newSize > maxSize) newSize = maxSize;
  elem.style.fontSize = newSize + "em";
}
```

The main difference is that I'm using the variable `currentSize` in the line `var newSize = parseFloat(currentSize) + multiplier * 0.2;`

Thank you to everyone who helped.

Comment: So I see what was the error - initially the `sizeable` element had no fontSize property so it translated to NaN (not a number).
And `fontSize || 1` makes it 1 so it can be used normally.

Answer (score 0):

```
var minSize = 1;
var maxSize = 5;

function resizeText(multiplier) {
    var elem = document.getElementById("sizeable");
    var newSize = parseFloat(elem.style.fontSize) + multiplier * 0.2;
    if (newSize < minSize) newSize = minSize;
    if (newSize > maxSize) newSize = maxSize;
    elem.style.fontSize = newSize + "em";
}
```

Comment: It works. You can check it here: http://zdg.ru/tmp/sizeable.html
See the page source code.

Comment: I've added in my question where I've put the code, but its not working.

Comment: open Javascript console in your browser and see if there are any errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p id="plustext"   onclick="resizeText(this,1)" >Hello</p> 
<p id="minustext"  onclick="resizeText(this,-1)">World</p>
```

javascript:

```
function resizeText(elem,multiplier) {
elem.count=elem.count || 0;
if(elem.count<2){
var currentSize = elem.style.fontSize || 1;
elem.style.fontSize = ( parseFloat(currentSize) + (multiplier * 0.2)) + "em";
elem.count++;
}

}
```

edit1 : if you want to increase and decrease after one click.

```
function resizeText(elem,multiplier) {
elem.count=elem.count || 0;
var currentSize = elem.style.fontSize || 1;
if(elem.count<1){
elem.style.fontSize = ( parseFloat(currentSize) + (multiplier * 0.2)) + "em";
elem.count++;
} else {
elem.style.fontSize = ( parseFloat(currentSize) - (multiplier * 0.2)) + "em";
elem.count--;
}

}
```

Comment: How would I get that to apply to my other text, which is in a table?

Comment: where u need to apply this ... just call onclick="resizeText(this,1)".. 
like i did in paragraph.

Comment: Yeah but that would always make the text bigger, what if the user wanted to make the text smaller? If you look at the code I've just added in to the question you might understand that at the minute I can make the text bigger or smaller depending on what was clicked, rather than just bigger or just smaller.

Comment: @benjs let me understand , if you want to bigger on one click and then second click decrease it. I also edit the answer.

Comment: Ok, well before all text with the id `sizeable` could be made bigger or smaller when the user clicks the button, but with yours the text can either have the `id="plustext"   onclick="resizeText(this,1)"` that will make it bigger or the `<p id="minustext"  onclick="resizeText(this,-1)">World</p>` that will make it smaller, whereas before the text could either be made bigger or smaller.

Comment: @benjs.1 ID's must be unique in a page by definition

Comment: Not necessary to pass this. We have event.srcElement.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you actually wanted to control the size of font and not the number of clicks.I hope this helps you to make it better than you expected.

```js
 var initialFontSize = getFontSize();
 var maxFontSize;
 var minFontSize;

 function getFontSize() {
   var temp = document.getElementById("sizeable").style.fontSize;
   if (temp) {
     return temp.substr(0, temp.indexOf("em"))
   } else {
     return 1;
   }
 }


 function resizeText(multiplier) {
   maxFontSize = parseFloat(initialFontSize) + multiplier * 0.4;
   minFontSize = parseFloat(initialFontSize) - multiplier * 0.4;

   var elem = document.getElementById("sizeable");
   var currentSize = getFontSize();
   if ((event.srcElement.id == "plustext" && currentSize < maxFontSize) || (event.srcElement.id == "minustext" && currentSize > maxFontSize)) {

     elem.style.fontSize = (parseFloat(currentSize) + (multiplier * 0.2)) + "em";

   }
 }
```

```html
<div id="sizeable">sdfsfsd</div>
<img id="plustext" alt="INCREASE TEXT SIZE" src="images/makeTextBigger.jpg " onclick="resizeText(1)" />|
<img id="minustext" alt="DECREASE TEXT SIZE" src="images/makeTextSmaller.jpg" onclick="resizeText(-1)" />
```